# Python code, should I thread? what to do?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I have this code, which listens for a command 'Updated Playlist' over sockets.
When it gets this command, it knows that the playlist in the database has been updated and it connects to the database and downloads the new playlist and then it starts playing these files.
I'm trying to find the best way about this because when it gets the command, then calls the Media_Player function, it will play all the videos in the playlist before it returns to listen to the sockets.

In the mean time if another 'Updated Playlist' command has been sent, the sender of this command gets an error because this code won't be listening. I want the media player to be playing non stop, but it also has to be listening constantly in case it has been told a new play list has been added.

Then if a new playlist has been added, it will know and when one of the files in the play list has finished playing it can switch over to the new playlist and keep going.

I don't know how to go about this, I thought I could have it all in the one process and just spawn off a new thread for each file in the play list, so it can go straight back to listening, but then how am I suppose to know when the thread has finished because each file in the playlist will be different lengths.

Also in the function listen_serv() see the line 'return data', does this mean its not closing the connection because its returning?

```
# Echo server program
import socket
import time
import Database as DB

def listen_serv():
    HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
    PORT = 50007              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected by', addr
    while 1:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if not data: break
        conn.sendall('OK')
        return data

    conn.close()


while 1:
    val= listen_serv()
    if val=='Updated Playlist':
        PlayList = DB.get_play_list()
        Media_Player(PlayList)#This isnt implemented yet
```

Comment: Are you aware of Python's Global Interpretor Lock issue? Only one thread runs at a time. You would be better off using the multi-processing library.

Answer (score 1):

You could have two processes running one is the server and the other is the MediaPlayer with a Queue in between.

The server pushes commands onto the queue where the MediaPlayer pops them, after playing each video simply check if theres anything on the queue, if there is pop it and play the new playlist.

```
import socket
import time
import Database as DB
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def listen_serv(queue):
    HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
    PORT = 50007              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected by', addr
    while 1:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        conn.sendall('OK')
        queue.put(data)
    conn.close()

def media_player(queue):
    while 1:
        val = queue.get() # This will block until theres something on the queue.
        if val == 'Updated Playlist':
            PlayList = DB.get_play_list()
            Media_Player(PlayList, queue) # Media_Player needs to check the queue and update when appropriate.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    server = Process(target = listen_serv, args = (q,))
    media_player = Process(target = media_player, args = (q,))
    server.start()
    media_player.start()
    server.join()
    media_player.join()
```

you can check if the queue is empty by `queue.empty()`
Im sure there are better implementations out there, if there are bugs/issues I apologize.

good luck.

Comment: While I wholeheartedly support the basic implementation strategy, there are several things to fix. listen_serv() needs to grow an additional while statement around the .accept() call. Parent process need to catch KeyboardInterrupt or have some other way to leave cleanly. Media_Player hardly needs access to the queue; that's what the calling function does.

Comment: I agree, I didn't implement a clean way to kill each process, you could simply add a command to the queue that tells each process to terminate, something like 'quit', as for the second issue, "when one of the files in the play list has finished playing it can switch over to the new playlist and keep going" so the Media_player needs to monitor the queue to know when to load the new play list ...

Comment: So what I can do is have the media player check a queue in between playing files and update accordingly. Would this be no different if I setup the media player to check for flag in a Database, or even check to see if a file exist?

Comment: I think I found an easier way using threads.
If i spawn two threads, one being the listen server, one being the media player. and I use threading.Event(). This way when the listen server gets it command, it sets the event. Then the media player can see this and then it can update its playlist from the DB. Is this a good way?

Comment: threading.Event() is quite primitive also note that threading in python isn't really multithreading since python has the global interpreter lock http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock but multiprocessing doesn't that issue but I doubt you need to worry about that, using queues is the most flexible way, since their thread safe, you can push multiple types in and are blocking when retrieving values, if you want to use threading.Event() go head, it just seems a bit limited.

Comment: But I only need a very very basic implementation of it. If the even is set, load new information from database. I've written up some code that works beautifully. So if this is a stable/safe way of doing it i would prefer it because its simple, and i understand how it works better then multi processes and queues.

Comment: there you go, you've answered your previous question ;) still its always good to learn different approaches Im glad you've got it working. if you ever need to do some more fancy stuff you know where to start.